# Get individual hostnames from round-robin DNS record

Tags: python, sockets, dns

I'm writing a script that will need to pull DNS records, which point to a round-robin type cluster.

For example, the cluster's name might be `WSCLUSTER`, but the 2 records that it points to would be `DMS1` and `DMS2`.

Using the Python `socket` module, how can I pull these hostnames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just `socket` is involved because you need to basically implement a DNS record lookup.  Have you thought about using [`dnspython`](http://www.dnspython.org/examples.html)?

```
import dns.resolver

answers = dns.resolver.query('WSCLUSTER', 'A')
for rdata in answers:
    print rdata
```